# What's the difference between ntfs-3g and lowntfs-3g?

Tags: ntfs, ntfs-3g

I've been having some performance issues with games on my NTFS drive. I share a steam library between Linux and Windows, which resides on a PCIe4 NVME, NTFS formatted. Running e.g Baldur's Gate 3 of it loads very slowly, compared to running it from my ext4, also on a pcie4 NVME. The difference is staggering, 15 seconds vs 60. Yet both drives are similar in terms of read specs.
There's also a CPU spike by the ntfs-3g driver while loading.

I tried pretty much everything to up the performance, like noatime, big_writes and the likes, nothing worked. Until I tried lowntfs-3g. I tried it as a last resort and it worked. It's very fast, as fast as the ext4!

So, what am I missing? What is the downside? I failed to find any info of this on the internet or man pages.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 (KDE Neon 5.27) with Xanmod kernel 6.4.10.

Answer (score 1):

That is a surprisingly undocumented thing, yes.

So, the honest answer is: `ntfs-3g` and `lowntfs-3g` are two different NTFS drivers. They do share some code, but it's actually not that much in the critical functions, for example `fuse_ntfs_read`: [ntfs-3g version](https://github.com/tuxera/ntfs-3g/blame/75dcdc2cf37478fad6c0e3427403d198b554951d/src/ntfs-3g.c#L1556), [lowntfs-3g version](https://github.com/tuxera/ntfs-3g/blame/75dcdc2cf37478fad6c0e3427403d198b554951d/src/lowntfs-3g.c#L1701).

As the name hints at, lowntfs-3g uses a lower-level FUSE API, and it seems it's faster. I can't say whether that's due to the low-level FUSE API being faster, or because the code is seemingly a few years newer and they just learned from the first revision.

`man 8 ntfs-3g` tells us that only lowntfs-3g can ignore case and downcase all filenames, while only ntfs-3g can handle alternative data streams (if you've not heard of these, you'd be forgiven!).

So, in essence, same software package, two different implementations of an NTFS driver. No clear recommendation from the developers to use one or the other.

I guess ntfs-3g is more likely to be thoroughly tested, because it's what everyone and their grandma defaults to – just as I would have done, and you have done. Bugs would have been found earlier.

I'm a bit surprised ext4 is only four times faster than ntfs-3g! That's a massive achievement for a FUSE driver, by the way; usually, any access to a file (e.g. on ext4) would just require a program to make a syscall, which saves the processor state (which describes the point in the program that was executing, and all the relevant registers in your CPU) and the scheduling state, and kicks of the getting of data in the kernel; as soon as the kernel is done getting the data your program asked for, execution of the program can continue, so the state of the process as it was executing kernel code is saved, and the state of the processor as it was executing the program code is restored, and the CPU jumps back to where your program left off when it did the syscall. (Details are of course more hairy, but that's the basic idea.)

In FUSE, File system in USErland, your program does a syscall (save program state, restore kernel state), the kernel determines that the file you ask about is on a FUSE filesystem, figures out which, and calls a function of that file system driver in userland (save kernel state, restore FUSE program state), that file system driver determines what it needs to read from the underlying block device, and does a syscall to do that read (save FUSE state, restore kernel state), the kernel does that read, returns the data (save kernel state, restore FUSE program state), the FUSE driver then assembles the data as requested, and returns it to the kernel (save FUSE program state, restore kernel state), and then the kernel can hand the requested data (if it's complete!) to the program (save kernel state, restore program state).

So, FUSE is literally an unholy feast of context switches (at least 6 instead of 2), with lots of CPU caches being potentially thrashed in between. This is really bad for performance (the smaller the individual read requests are, the worse!). That's why I'm so positively surprised about ntfs-3g's performance, and *amazed* by the lowntfs-3g performance you report!